# Get matched and unmatched count from another collection mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, lookup, mongodb-lookup

I have two collection present in mongodb database. one **status** column is common. I need **matched and unmatched count** from both the collection based on **status** column.
I have written some code but it fetching only matched count.

```
db.properties.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "old_properties_data",
            localField: "identifier",
            foreignField: "identifier",
            as: "col2docs"
        }
    },
    
  
    {"$group" : {_id:"_id", count:{$sum:1}}}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first `$group` by `identifier` to get the total match count. Then You can use uncorreleated subquery in [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-subqueries-on-a-joined-collection) to get the total size of `old_properties_data`. Finally do a `$subtract` to get the total unmatched count.

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/t6KMUFcqu9z) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you for the Mongo Playground code. but i need complete group of matched and unmatched count with respect to identifier. like if identifier match with any identifier in other collection so match count increased and the total unmatched count is total count - matched count

Comment: updated the answer and playground link. You may have a look to see if thats what your are looking for :)